# How to Subtotal Value with MAX

Tags: sql

1.I have data as follows (just a subset - there are 20K records)

```
    sku,id
    1   1
    1   2
    1   2
    1   2
    1   3
    1   4
    1   1
    1   2
    1   3
    1   4
    1   4
    1   4
    1   5
    1   6
    1   6
    2   1
    2   1
    2   2
    2   3
    2   3
    2   3
    2   4
    2   4
    2   5
    2   5
    2   6
    2   7
    2   1
    2   2
    2   3
```

The above values translate to

```
1 = 4 records
1 = 6 records
2 = 7 records
2 = 3 records
```

The MAX would just give me 6 for one and 7 for 2

The actual total is 1 = 10 and 2 = 10

How do I sum up to get the correct values?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images.

Comment: I think you need the answer as 6 and MAX function will give you that. If you have any other logic, Please care to explain.

Comment: `select max(id), count(*) from t` ?

Comment: See this post here to help you get an answer faster: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you simply mean you want rows with the two highest id values?

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by a sequence.

Comment: And remember that the result-set order is undefined, unless ORDER BY is used.

Comment: Yes rows with the two highest values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `order by` and some way of limiting rows.  In standard SQL this would be:

```
select t.*
from t
order by id desc
fetch first 2 rows only;
```

However, some databases might use `limit` or `select top` or some other method.

Comment: @JeremyReynolds . . . Perhaps not.  But given the data in your question, this returns what you want.  And it seems to be doing what you are asking for.  You might want to ask a new question with more clarity -- it is unclear what you mean by "sequence" so I guess I basically discounted that.

Comment: Edited question posted.

Comment: @JeremyReynolds and this one

Answer (score 0):

No handling of ties here. Thousands of other questions handle this topic.

```
select sku, id
from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by id desc) rn
    from T
) t
where rn <= 2
order by rn desc;
```